# Is there a way to combine foreachs on .net?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I have a series of arround 20 different arrays,
and for only an asthetic point of view of the code would like to have one foreach instead of multiple calls

**What I have:**

```
foreach (var item in actionEvent.Colors)
    UpdateComponent(item.ComponentId, item);
foreach (var item in actionEvent.Links)
    UpdateComponent(item.ComponentId, item);
foreach (var item in actionEvent.Texts)
    UpdateComponent(item.ComponentId, item);
```

**What I would love to have**

```
foreach (var item in actionEvent.Colors, actionEvent.Links,actionEvent.Texts)
    UpdateComponent(item.ComponentId, item);
```

I don't know if it exists something like union  or something of the kind (and no, I can't iterate over actionEvent because there are arrays that would case the rest of the code to explode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use concat (assuming they're all the same type):

```
foreach (var item in actionEvent.Colors.Concat(actionEvent.Links).Concat(actionEvent.Texts))
    UpdateComponent(item.ComponentId, item);
```

You can also use `Union` instead of `Concat` if you want to check for and remove duplicates.

If they're all using the same overload of `UpdateComponent`, but have different types (For example, if the method is defined as `UpdateComponent(int, object)`, but you might have `Link`, `Text`, `Color`) - then you'll need to cast the collection, like so:

```
foreach (var item in actionEvent.Colors.Cast<object>()
                                .Concat(actionEvent.Links.Cast<object>())
                                .Concat(actionEvent.Texts.Cast<object>())
    UpdateComponent(item.ComponentId, item);
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the answer, it didn't worked for me,

 the first one trhew this error: System.Collections.Generic.List<ComponentTypeColorDto>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat'"

The second one the same but for Cast

Comment: @saikios You'll need to add `using System.Linq` at the top of your file. I'll edit my post to include it when I'm back at my desk

Comment: I'm using it

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

Comment: That's... strange. Are you able to write `Enumerable.Cast<object>(actionEvent.Links)` without an error?

Comment: Yes @Rob, and your code throws me the error when I execute it, but not when I compile it

Comment: Is `actionEvent.Links` defined as `dynamic`?

Comment: Yes, It is a dynamic

Comment: @Saikios In that case you cannot use extension methods. You'd need to write  `Enumerable.Concat(actionLink.Colors, ..)`, `Enumerable.Cast(actionLink.Colors)` instead of `actionLink.Colors.Concat(..)` etc. At that point it's probably a lot messier than using multiple for loops. Is there a reason you need it to be dynamic?

Comment: Just standard with the rest of the code, not a particular reason beyond that point.

I will have to stay with the loops, the Enumerable.Concat only alow me to concat two at a time, but thanks for the help!

Comment: @Saikios No worries! Just so you're aware, `dynamic` means all resolutions on the object are done at run-time, which has a non-negligible performance impact. Unless there's an explicit reason to use `dynamic`, I'd advise using strongly typed members